# Macbook 13" - 32 bit or 64 bit? how do I check?

Tags: linux, macos, 64-bit, 32-bit

I don't know how to check if my Macbook 13" white is 32-bit or 64-bit, how do I check that for any Mac or Linux system?

Comment: Interestingly, this question has 14 votes at StackOverflow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246007/how-to-determine-whether-a-given-linux-is-32-bit-or-64-bit

Comment: For **Linux**: http://superuser.com/questions/29943/how-do-i-know-if-my-linux-kernel-is-running-in-32bit-or-64bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select About this Mac from the Apple menu, then click More Info

.
[image]

.
Mac OS X 10.5 (or greater) is a 64-bit operating system. Intel Core 2 Duo, Intel Xeon, and PowerPC G5 are 64-bit processors. However, 64-bit Stata for Mac is available only for 64-bit Intel-based Macs.

Linux or MAC

Type the uname -a command. Depending on the platform, you may see

> [cph@gaylord ~]$ uname -a

Linux gaylord.stata.com 2.6.11-1.27_FC3 #1 Tue May 17 20:24:57 EDT 2005 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

> [cph@caddo ~]$ uname -a

Linux caddo.stata.com 2.6.9-5.0.5.EL #1 SMP Fri Apr 8 14:20:58 EDT 2005 ia64 ia64 ia64 GNU/Linux

> [cph@tango ~]$ uname -a

Linux tango.stata.com 2.6.10-1.771_FC2smp #1 SMP Mon Mar 28 01:10:51 EST 2005 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

In the above listing, 'gaylord' (x86_64 GNU/Linux) and 'caddo' (ia64 GNU/Linux) are 64-bit compliant. 'tango' (i386 GNU/Linux) is only a 32-bit platform.

[Source of Information](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/win/64bit.html)